# Php Page refresh not keeping variable value

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a file which works fine. I need the page to refresh once the upload button is pressed so that the file is shown on the page without the user having to refresh the page. This also works fine. I want to change the varailble $refresh to 1 but even if I put the code after the reload of the page it keeps the $refresh variable as 2. How to I get the variable to stay as 1.

```
$refresh = "2";
$dir_path = "Dir10/";
$items = scandir($dir_path);
echo 'List of files in ' . $dir_path;

 foreach($items as $item){
 echo '<li>' . $item . '</li>';
}

echo '<br>';  
echo '<form  method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
     <input type="file" name="file1"><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
     </form>';   

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //when upload button is press upload file 
  $tmp_name = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
$path=getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dir_path;
$name = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES['file1']['name'];
$success = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $name);
header("Location:task10.php"); //refresh page
//echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'>"; this also does the same 
$refresh = "1";
```

Comment: The script will be executed on each request. So you can't keep the value of a variable. Why do you need the refresh?

Comment: Later in the program I need to run a function only is $refresh is set to 1, but its always at 2 because of the refresh. I need to refresh so the file names will be listed without the user having to refresh the browser. If there is another way of showing the files names without using a refresh that would also work.

Comment: have a look into sessions: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Comment: You have to see what you put inside task10.php because header will leave the current page and move to another page (task10.php)... to refresh the current page you can use the trick $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' 
    || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
header('Location: '.$protocol.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
exit;

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it right by using a java script. Put the content I want to refresh in div tags then ran this script where I want to refresh.

```
echo '<div id="reload">'   ;
echo '<strong>'.'List of files in Dir10'.'</strong> ';  //display list of files
foreach($items as $item){
 echo '<li>' . $item . '</li>';
}

 echo '<script type="text/javascript">
$("#refresh").load("task10.php #refresh");
</script>';
```